# Ask for option in VBS

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, proxy, windows-10

I am new to VBS scripting and need your help and advice on how to make my script work with choices.

My work network uses a proxy and my home network does not, I have managed to get the script working in order to toggle the proxy from on to off whenever I require but this still gives leaves me wondering whether it is enabled or disabled.

I would like the VBS script to ask me "

> 1. Enable Proxy / 2. Disable Proxy

" and then run through the section of code corresponding to the choice.

I don't have any VBS experience and I am completely out of my depth with this and would appreciate any help with this.

```
Option Explicit 
Dim WSHShell, strSetting
Dim ObjShell
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Elevate VBS to run as Administrator
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
    Set ObjShell = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
    WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
    " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
    Wscript.Quit
End if

'Determine current proxy setting and toggle to oppisite setting
strSetting = wshshell.regread("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable")
If strSetting = 1 Then 
NoProxy
Else Proxy
End If

'Subroutine to Toggle Proxy Setting to ON "Tested & Working"
Sub Proxy 
WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 1, "REG_DWORD"
wscript.sleep 500
WSHShell.Exec "cmd /C netsh.exe winhttp import proxy source=ie"
End Sub

'Subroutine to Toggle Proxy Setting to OFF "Tested & Working"
Sub NoProxy 
WSHShell.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 0, "REG_DWORD"
wscript.sleep 500
WSHShell.Exec "cmd /C netsh.exe winhttp reset proxy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Yes/No/Cancel [`MsgBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x):

```
answer = MsgBox("Enable Proxy?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion)
Select Case answer
  Case vbYes : Proxy
  Case vbNo  : NoProxy
  Case Else  : WScript.Echo "Cancelled"
End Select
```